# Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>>>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, callback, mapbox, async.js

I'm using a React library called Leaflet consuming data from Mapbox API to create a map in may delivery services application. I created a method called loadOptions to select one specific address returned from Mapbox API that is loaded from the string that the user typed.

I created a folder called "Orders" which contains index.tsx, ProductCard.tsx, ProductsList.tsx and api.ts (hits last one contains the function that consumes the Mapbox API)

So, I'm having this following error:

```
ERROR in src/Orders/OrderLocation.tsx:64:25

TS2322: Type '(inputValue: string, callback: (places: Place[]) => void) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(inputValue: string, callback: (options: OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>>) => void) => void | Promise<OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>>>'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>>>'.
    Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>>>'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>>'.
    62 |                         placeholder="Digite um endereço para entregar o pedido"
    63 |                         className="filter"
  > 64 |                         loadOptions={loadOptions}
       |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
    65 |                         onChange={value => handleChangeSelect(value as Place)}
    66 |                     />
    67 |                 </div>
```

**Ordelocations.tsx component**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
import { fetchLocalMapbox } from '../api';

const initialPosition = {
    lat: -18.9110558,
    lng: -48.26201
}

type Place = {
    //Props
    label?: string;
    value?: string;
    position: {
        lat: number;
        lng: number;
    };
}

function OrderLocation() {

    //State
    const [address, setAddress] = useState<Place>({
        position: initialPosition
    });

    const loadOptions = async (inputValue: string, callback: (places: Place[]) => void) => {
        const response = await fetchLocalMapbox(inputValue);

        const places = response.data.features.map((item: any) => {
            return ({
                label: item.place_name,
                value: item.place_name,
                position: {
                    lat: item.center[1],
                    lng: item.center[0]
                }
            });
        });

        callback(places);
    };

    const handleChangeSelect = (place: Place) => {
        setAddress(place);
        /*   onChangeLocation({
              latitude: place.position.lat,
              longitude: place.position.lng,
              address: place.label!
          }); */
    };

    return (
        <div className="order-location-container">
            <div className="order-location-content">
                <h3 className="order-location-title">
                    Selectione onde o pedido deve ser entregue
                </h3>
                <div className="filter-container">
                    <AsyncSelect
                        placeholder="Digite um endereço para entregar o pedido"
                        className="filter"
                        loadOptions={loadOptions}
                        onChange={value => handleChangeSelect(value as Place)}
                    />
                </div>
                <MapContainer
                    center={address.position}
                    zoom={13}
                    scrollWheelZoom
                >
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    <Marker position={address.position}>
                        <Popup>
                            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default OrderLocation;
```

**api.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = 'https://dfdeliver.herokuapp.com'; /*http://localhost:8080*/
const mapboxToken = '';

export function fetchProducts() {
    return axios(`${API_URL}/produtos`)
}

export function fetchLocalMapbox(local: string) {
    return axios(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${local}.json?access_token=${mapboxToken}`)
}
```

I really need help because I have to deliver this project next week. thanks people!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error, the problem is that your `loadOptions` function does not match the expected return value of the `loadOptions` property you're passing it into, according to this part of the error:

```
    62 |                         placeholder="Digite um endereço para entregar o pedido"
    63 |                         className="filter"
  > 64 |                         loadOptions={loadOptions}
       |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
    65 |                         onChange={value => handleChangeSelect(value as Place)}
```

So, what's wrong with the return value? Well your function returns `Promise<void>`. Why do we know this? It's because it is an asynchronous function, which ultimately performs some actions on the places using the callback parameter, but it does not return a value. So it returns `void` asynchronously, hence `Promise<void>`.

On the other hand, the `loadOptions` property is expecting a method which returns `void | Promise<OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>>>`. This means you can either change your function so that it still returns `void`, but does so synchronously, or you can keep it asynchronous, but return the `OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>>` value instead of nothing.

Option 1: Return `void`

```
const loadOptions = (inputValue: string, callback: (places: Place[]) => void) => {
    
    // use .then(...) callbacks to turn this synchronous
    fetchLocalMapbox(inputValue)
    .then(response => {
        const places = response.data.features.map((item: any) => ({
            label: item.place_name,
            value: item.place_name,
            position: {
                lat: item.center[1],
                lng: item.center[0]
            }
        }));

        callback(places);
    });

};
```

Option 2: Return `Promise<OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>>>`

```
const loadOptions = async (inputValue: string, callback: (places: Place[]) => void) => {
    const response = await fetchLocalMapbox(inputValue);

    const places = response.data.features.map((item: any) => {
        return ({
            label: item.place_name,
            value: item.place_name,
            position: {
                lat: item.center[1],
                lng: item.center[0]
            }
        });
    });

    callback(places);

    // return the Place[], assuming that it inherits from the
    // OptionsOrGroups<Place, GroupBase<Place>> type, of course
    return places;
};
```

Comment: I used your first option to let the function return void and let it synchronous. Thank you so much man!!!